# Not able to annotate on plot - KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, annotations

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as date
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import calendar
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

start = date.datetime(2014,1,1)
end = date.datetime.today()

stock = '^NSEI'
data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
fig , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4), dpi =500)

data.plot(y='Close', ax = ax)
```

Here i am omitting a section of code but the product is :

```
exceptthursday 
Out[4]: 
                  Day
Date                 
2011-01-26  Wednesday
2011-03-02  Wednesday
2011-04-12    Tuesday
2011-04-22     Friday
2011-08-15     Monday
              ...
2020-05-25     Monday
2020-10-02     Friday
2020-11-16     Monday
2020-11-30     Monday
2020-12-25     Friday

[114 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then we have the following code:

```
for anotate in (exceptthursday.index + BDay()):
    ax.annotate('holliday', xy=(anotate, data['Close'].loc[anotate]),  xycoords='data',
                xytext=(-30, 40), textcoords='offset points',
                size=13, ha='center', va="baseline",
                bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", alpha=0.1),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="wedge,tail_width=0.5", alpha=0.1));
```

When i run this code i am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: Timestamp('2011-01-27 00:00:00')
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error because the `start` is in year 2014 so why is the error in year 2011?

Comment: You are passing `exceptthursday`'s indices for iteration. Which contains timestamps starting from **2011-01-26**. The error must come in `data['Close'].loc[anotate]` if I'm not wrong. Because data's start is from `date.datetime(2014,1,1)` which doesn't have the 2011's timestamp

Comment: @LazyCoder Yes buddy you are right there is a problem with my data. Thanks for your help. If you could just post it in answer i will award the bounty and close the question. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `exceptthursday'`s indices for iteration. Which contains timestamps starting
from **2011-01-26**.
The error must come in
`data['Close'].loc[anotate]`.
if I'm not wrong. Because data's start is from `date.datetime(2014,1,1)` which doesn't have the **2011**'s timestamp

Glad to help.Happy coding!:)